Weirdness with WriteableBitmap in WPF
I'm creating a gray8 writeable bitmap in WPF/.Net 8.
When I set this to an Image Source, the result is a completely black image - of around the correct size.
If I save the writeable bitmap (using a PngEncoder), the image saves as I would expect. If I reload the png image from disk to the Image control then it displays perfectly fine.
However, If I recreate the image and resave it and reload it, it is not displayed - the original image is retained.
I'm mainly concerned about know what I need to do to make the writeable bitmap not appear black as I don't have a need to save and so on.
The intent of the bitmap is to show a series of bars whose darkness corresponds to the values in an array - a kind of density histogram
public BitmapSource CreateLineWeightImage()
{
    if (LineWeights == null) throw new InvalidOperationException("Must GetLineWeights first");

    WriteableBitmap lineWeights = new WriteableBitmap(LineWeightImageWidth, OriginalImage.PixelHeight, 96, 96, PixelFormats.Gray8, null);
    lineWeights.Lock();
    unsafe
    {
        for (int y = 0; y < lineWeights.PixelHeight; ++y)
        {
            for (int x = 0; x < LineWeightImageWidth; ++x)
            {
                byte* PixelPtr = (byte*)lineWeights.BackBuffer + y * lineWeights.BackBufferStride + x;

                *((byte*)PixelPtr) = (byte)LineWeights[y];
            }
        }
    }

    lineWeights.Unlock();
    LineWeightsImage = lineWeights;
    return lineWeights;
}

Thanks
Iain

I think your question is effectively a duplicate of this one How to define 8 bit greyscale bitmap. Without the correct palette info then the indexed colours may well be all black (or some other memory fill pattern).

@MartinBrown PixelFormats.Gray8 does not need a palette.

Methinks you should move those Lock() and Unlock() calls to a try/finally block; otherwise your program will blow-up if anything bad happens in your unsafe block.

Out of curiosity, what is LineWeights and why are you casting its elements to Byte? If the elements aren't actually byte values then what is the risk of a non-0-255 value being cast?

You could replace the inner loop (over x) by System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe.InitBlock((byte*)lineWeights.BackBuffer + y * lineWeights.BackBufferStride, (byte)LineWeights[y], (uint)lineWeights.PixelWidth);

Dai - I am working on identify page numbers in a sequence of scanned pages to see if there is an interruption due to bad scanning.  The lineweights are a visualisation (in effect) of how many black pixels there are on the line and thus an indicator of where lines are, so I can extrac the top and bottom lines on a page and work out which has the page number.  Thanks to others for comments

You have to tell the WriteableBitmap which changes were made to its BackBuffer, by calling the AddDirtyRect method before Unlock:
lineWeights.AddDirtyRect(new Int32Rect(
    0, 0, lineWeights.PixelWidth, lineWeights.PixelHeight));

lineWeights.Unlock();


That is exactly what the issue was.  many things
